# Setting up Konico Minolta 1400w printer on Windows Vista 32-bit

Tags: windows-vista, printer, troubleshooting, setup

One of my neighbors asked me to help them setup this old printer on their computer (their other printer is broken) so after fighting with it for about an hour but to no avail. Every time I try to install it, Windows just recognizes it as a "print to file printer" as in it will only print to an output file.

Comment: FYI: Everyone's question is urgent to them, putting that in your question wont get you any answers quicker, and might actually annoy some people.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you download the latest drivers from the official website, install them before plugging in the printer, then plug in the printer?
- Did you try rebooting?
- Did you check Device Manager and see if it shows any warnings or errors?

Comment: Done the first two, but haven't tried the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the drivers from below mentioned URL :

http://printer.konicaminolta.com/support/current_printers/pp1400w_sup.htm#vista

Scroll down, at the bottom you will find drivers for windows Vista 32 bits. You will also find installation guide in PDF with the drivers.

Hope this would help.